# Reading in text file gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, file-io, postfix-notation

I am attempting to read this .txt file into my program (as an improvement over manual input) and i am having trouble converting my methods to accept the input txt file.  i get a arrayindexoutofboundsexception on line "infix[--pos]='\0';"

```
class Functions {
    void postfix(char infix[], char post[]) {
        int position, und = 1;
        int outposition = 0;
        char topsymb = '+';
        char symb;
        Stack opstk = new Stack();
        opstk.top = -1;
        for (position = 0; (symb = infix[position]) != '\0'; position++) {
            if (isoperand(symb))
                post[outposition++] = symb;
            else {
                if (opstk.isempty() == 1)
                    und = 1;
                else {
                    und = 0;
                    topsymb = opstk.pop();
                }
                while (und == 0 && precedence(topsymb, symb) == 1) {
                    post[outposition++] = topsymb;
                    if (opstk.isempty() == 1)
                        und = 1;
                    else {
                        und = 0;
                        topsymb = opstk.pop();
                    }
                }// end while
                if (und == 0)
                    opstk.push(topsymb);
                if (und == 1 || (symb != ')'))
                    opstk.push(symb);
                else
                    topsymb = opstk.pop();
            }// end else
        }// end for
        while (opstk.isempty() == 0)
            post[outposition++] = opstk.pop();
        post[outposition] = '\0';
    }// end postfix function

    int precedence(char topsymb, char symb) {
        /* check precedence and return 0 or 1 */
        if (topsymb == '(')
            return 0;
        if (symb == '(')
            return 0;
        if (symb == ')')
            return 1;
        if (topsymb == '$' && symb == '$')
            return 0;
        if (topsymb == '$' && symb != '$')
            return 1;
        if (topsymb != '$' && symb == '$')
            return 0;
        if ((topsymb == '*' || topsymb == '/') && (symb != '$'))
            return 1;
        if ((topsymb == '+' || topsymb == '-') && (symb == '-' || symb == '+'))
            return 1;
        if ((topsymb == '+' || topsymb == '-') && (symb == '*' || symb == '/'))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    } /* end precedence function */

    private boolean isoperand(char symb) {
        /* Return 1 if symbol is digit and 0 otherwise */
        if (symb >= '0' && symb <= '9')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }/* end isoperand function */

}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Functions f = new Functions();
        char infix[] = new char[80];
        char post[] = new char[80];
        int pos = 0;
        char c;
        System.out.println("\nEnter an expression is infix form : ");

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infix.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                infix = str.toCharArray();
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        infix[--pos] = '\0';
        System.out.println("The original infix expression is : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            System.out.print(infix[i]);
        f.postfix(infix, post);
        System.out.println("\nThe postfix expression is : ");
        for (int i = 0; post[i] != '\0'; i++)
            System.out.println(post[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `pos` is -1 when it reaches that line. what is `pos` used for in your code?

Comment: Boy does this code look like C instead of Java.  I suggest you take a look at some beginning Java documentation online.  Dealing with arrays in this manner is just not typical and leads to exceptions like you are getting.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/131237-infix-parsing/ - You should really try writing your own code so you have familiarity with it, rather than using some one else's and then asking for help when it doesn't work.

Comment: i believe at the end of the post in that forum. it says that 'you may modify' the code.  i wasnt attempting to plagiarize, simply to use similar code to solve a different problem.  im trying to read in from a file, not manual input.

Answer (score 0):

Do should never ever do like this:

```
try {
...
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

You loose some essential information about your code-running.

At lease you should print the stack trace to follow the investigation:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

You may have a FileNotFound exception.

In addition you try to index your array to -1 in `infix[--pos]`, pos is set to 0 before this statement.

Answer (score 0):

1) Totally aside, but I think line in main should read:System.out.println("\nEnter an expression in infix form : ");
2) As well, i agree about the catch statement. You already have narrowed it down to being an IOExcpetion, but you can find so much more info out by printing wither of the following inside the catch
         System.err.println(e.getMessage()); or e.printStackTrace()

**Now to answer your question.** You are initializing pos to the value 0, but the you are doing a PREINCREMENT on the line infix[--pos] = '\0'; so pos becomes -1 (clearly outside the scope of the array bounddaries).

I think you want to change that to a post increment infix[pos--] = '\0';. Perhaps?

And yes, your code DOES Look like C...